# obstructions to embeddings of manifolds into Grassmannians

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, grassmannians, embeddings, affine-grassmannian, obstruction-theory

Let $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the Grassmannian consisting of $k$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $AG_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the "affine Grassmannian" consisting of $k$-dimensional planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a manifold $M$ of dimension $m$, are there any methods to study whether $M$ can be embedded into $G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $AG_k(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

When studying the embedding/immersion problem of manifolds into Euclidean spaces, I learned that there are some obstructions by Stiefel-Whitney class from lecture notes. How about embedding problems into Grassmannians?

Comment: Stiefel whitney classes give obstructions for embeddings $f:M\rightarrow N$ for arbitrary manifolds as we have an exact sequence of vector bundles $0\rightarrow TM\rightarrow f^*TN \rightarrow NN\rightarrow 0$. But the problem is now more delicate because $f^*w(TN)$ is not known (even if the SW classes of TN are given).

Comment: I have not done any calculations for the Grassmannians but one should be able to glance information for this sequence.

Comment: I suppose you should pose a more specific question. In this generality, you can use the Whitney embedding theorem to embed a compact $m$-manifold into the Grassmannian whenever $2m\leq k(n-k)$. Probably you do not want this embedding, but embeddings whose homotopy class in $[M,G_k(\mathbb{R}^n)]$ satisfies some  conditions, or embeddings with significantly sharper bounds... There are things like h-principles for immersions or Weiss' embedding calculus, but without further information it is difficult to know if these things help.

Comment: @ThomasRot Thanks, Thomas! In your comment, since $N$ is not assumed to be embedded in an ambient Riemannian manifold, how to define $NN$? Does it mean the normal bundle of $N$? Where can I find the exact sequence?

Comment: Yes it means the normal bundle. If you want you can take a Riemannian metric on $TN$ and take the complement and pull it back to $M$.

Comment: @ThomasRot How to get the exact sequence? Could you give me  references?

Comment: I think this should be in any reference which discusses the normal bundle, e.g. Bott and Tu .

Comment: It is almost tautological...